# What's the right version of sprockets and tilt for Rails 4.2.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For Rails 4.2.0 app, what's right version of `sprockets' and`tilt' which are used for assets precompile? Currently we have version 3.2.0 for sprockets and it is causing failing of assets precompile. Obviously we need to specify version for both sprockets and tilt in `Gemfile`. We tried 2.12.3/1.3.7 and 2.12.3/1.3.3 (sprockets/tilt) and it seems not generating right assets. Bundler is 1.3.5 with the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sprockets there is a issue here [Github](https://github.com/vigetlabs/gulp-rails-pipeline/issues/19)

which is talking about downgrading to version sprockets 2.12.3